# translating C++ to MIPS - trying to make sense of the mips code

Tags: c++, assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

```
struct ProductionUnit
{
    unsigned short  yield; 
    short  id;
    bool  active;
};
 

ProductionUnit  units[1000];
```

Convert to MIPS the following piece of code

```
for( int i{0}; i<1000; i++ )
    if( units[i].active )
        totalSum += units[i].yield;
```

The value of totalSum is already in $s7 and is already initialized to zero. The address of units is already loaded in $s0.
All data members of ProductionUnit are stored in memory next to each other (no padding) and in the same order in which they are declared.

MIPS:
My friend sent me the translated mips code and I'd like to understand it a bit. active will be accessed from position 3 so we're shifting left. short is 2 bytes. so if we shit left by 2 in just one instruction it'll move 4 bytes and take us to position 3 right?

sll $t0, $s0, 1 # $t0 = i << 1

sll $t1, $t0, 1 # $t1 = i << 2

add $t2, $s0, $t1 # $t2 = 3i

lw $t3, 0($t2) # $t3 = units[3i]

beqz $t3, end # if units[3i] == 0, goto end

lw $t4, 0($t2) # $t4 = units[3i]

add $s7, $s7, $t4 # totalSum += units[3i]

addi $s0, $s0, 1 # i++

j loop # goto loop

end:

Comment: Recommendation: Take a shot at writing the assembly code and ask questions, if necessary, about the code. We will be able to help you much better if we can see where you are getting stuck.

Comment: First to do looks to determine the size of each types (`unsigned short`, `short`, `bool`, `int`) by searching for them from your documents or define them by yourself, depending of what the assignment expects.

Comment: Also check if unaligned load is allowed in your system. If not, you may require multiple instructions to load the value of `units[i].yield` (after determining its address), especially if the size of `bool` is 1.

Comment: Though it may not directly give you the answer, [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ExGMr4r9T) may give you some hints.

Answer (score 2):

There is a struct, and an array of that struct.  A struct has a layout — here an example is that `yield` has offset +0 (and occupies also +1), `id` is at +2 (and occupies also +3), and `active` has offset +4.

Since MIPS has fairly specific alignment requirements, then there would normally be padding to make the total size of the struct a multiple of at least 2 (the max alignment requirement for the elements/types within that struct).  This padding after will allow an array's next element to be properly aligned.

Since padding is disallowed by your requirements, then the alternatives are to make the `bool` occupy 2 bytes so the struct is still 6 bytes, or, use an unnatural alignment size (the struct is 5 bytes), which means that the `short`s will have to be accessed as individual bytes.

So, with padding or two-byte bool, the next element in the array will be at offset +6, which is then the scaling factor for the array.  Thus, `units[i].active` has an address computation of `i`*6 + 4 + `units`.  Dereference that to access a byte for the padding version or access a 16-bit value for the two-byte bool version.

---

Control structures — if, for — follow patterns and have equivalent patterns in assembly language using if-goto-label form.

```
for( int i{0}; i<1000; i++ )
    if( units[i].active )
        totalSum += units[i].yield;
```

First decompose the `for` into a `while`:

```
i=0;
while ( i < 1000 ) {
    if( units[i].active )
        totalSum += units[i].yield;
    i++;
}
```

Next, introduce labels and if-goto for the while loop:

```
    i=0;
loop1:
    if ( i >= 1000 ) goto endLoop1;
    if( units[i].active )
        totalSum += units[i].yield;
    i++;
    goto loop1;
endLoop1:
```

And introduce labels for the if-statement:

```
    i=0;
loop1:
    if ( i >= 1000 ) goto endLoop1;
    if ( ! units[i].active ) goto endIf1;
    totalSum += units[i].yield;
endIf1:
    i++;
    goto loop1;
endLoop1:
```

This if-goto-label form is fairly easy to translate to assembly language.  Labels translate directly; goto's translate directly using `j` instructions; if-goto's translate using compare and branch instruction sequences, or just branch instructions when sufficiently simple.

Comment: Note that the question says "no padding" and that [the size of `bool` need not be 1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Comment: @MikeCAT, good point.